# Error setting dtypes of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was attempting to make a 1x5 numpy array with the following code

```
testArray = np.array([19010913, "Hershey", "Bar", "Birthday", 12.34])
```

but encountered the unwanted result that

```
testArray.dtype
dtype("<U8")
```

I want each column to be a specific data type, so I attempted to input this

```
testArray = np.array([19010913, "Hershey", "Bar", "Birthday", 12.34],
    dtype=[('f0','<i8'),('f1','<U64'),('f2','<U64'),('f3','<U64'),('f4','<f10')] )
```

but got the error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:1:
DeprecationWarning: Specified size is invalid for this data type.
Size will be ignored in NumPy 1.7 but may throw an exception in
future versions. if __name__ == '__main__':
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-d2c44d88c8a5> in <module>()
----> 1 testArray = np.array([19840913, "Hershey", "Bar",
"Birthday", 64.25], dtype=[('f0','<i8'),('f1','<U64'),('f2','<U64'), ('f3','<U64'),('f4','<f10')] )

TypeError: 'int' does not support the buffer interface
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I am not sure if `f10` is something known.

Note that structured arrays need to be defined as "list of tuples". Try the following:

```
testArray = np.array([(19010913, "Hershey", "Bar", "Birthday", 12.34)],
dtype=[('f0','<i8'),('f1','<U64'),('f2','<U64'),('f3','<U64'),('f4','<f8')])
```

See also [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) and [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html) for different ways of defining `np.dtype`s and structured arrays.

Edit:

For multiple rows in the same structure, define each row of your array as a separate tuple in the list.

```
dt = np.dtype([('f0','<i8'),('f1','<U64'),('f2','<U64'),('f3','<U‌64'),('f4','<f8')])

testArray = np.array([(19010913, "Hershey", "Bar", "Birthday", 12.34), (123, "a", "b", "c", 56.78)], dtype=dt)
```

Comment: How would I make a 2x5 numpy array with each column having its own data type, as opposed to making an flat array of lists of tupple

Comment: You can have 5 columns of the same dtype, or 5 fields with different dtypes, but not both.

Comment: Just define each row of your array as a separate tuple in the list:

Comment: dt = np.dtype([('f0','<i8'),('f1','<U64'),('f2','<U64'),('f3','<U64'),('f4','<f8')])

Comment: testArray = np.array([(19010913, "Hershey", "Bar", "Birthday", 12.34), (123, "a", "b", "c", 56.78)],
dtype=dt)